# 'import' and 'from import' behaves differently

Tags: python, python-3.x

As per my understanding, the difference between 'import' and 'from import' in Python is: 'import' imports the whole library, 'from import' imports a specific member or members of the library, and there should not be any behavioral difference.

As per this, I was expecting both the test1.py and test2.py to show the same result i.e. "Lucky". But it is different for test2.py. Can anyone explain why?

**mymodule.py**

```
message = "Happy"

def set_message(msg):
    global message
    message = msg
```

**test1.py**

```
import mymodule

mymodule.set_message("Lucky")

print(mymodule.message) #output is Lucky
```

**test2.py**

```
from mymodule import *

set_message("Lucky")

print(message) #output is Happy
```

Comment: Think of importing things as simple assignment statements, and the behavior you see makes more sense.

Comment: Both make the entire module available. The difference is in which *names* are added to the global scope. (That is, no matter which form you use, `sys.modules['mymodule']` gives you access to anything in the module.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'import' imports the whole library, 'from import' imports a specific member or members of the library, and there should not be any behavioral difference.

Both versions - assuming the module has not already been imported - cause the top-level code to execute and a `module` object to be created.

`import ...` means that the module object is assigned to the corresponding name in the local namespace. (The reason the `.` syntax works is that the global variables from when the module's code was running, become *attributes of* that modle object.)

`from ... import *` means that Python *iterates over the attributes* of the module object, and assigns *each name* into the current namespace, similarly.

For subsequent code, the `module` object itself *is the global namespace in which its functions run*.

Your `test2.py` calls a method from `mymodule`, causing it to do a global lookup of `message`. That lookup *finds the `message` attribute of the module object*, and *replaces it*. The `message` global variable in your own code is unchanged, because neither was *that* name reassigned, nor was the *value* modified (it was replaced). It is the same as if you do:

```
# Functions are the easiest way to get an object with mutable attributes
def namespace(): pass
namespace.a = 3
a = namespace.a # "import" the name
namespace.a = 4 # replace the value; `a` does not change
```